# dynamic tag clouds in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tags, tag-cloud

I have implemented tag clouds in Ruby on Rails from scratch, using [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/382-tagging) tutorial.

When you click on a tag on my photoblog, say *Tokyo*, all photos tagged with *Tokyo* are listed. I now want to add 2 things to make my tag cloud more dynamic, so that it allows you to narrow down listings:

- The tag cloud should be updated dynamically, such that it now displays **only** tags associated to the remaining photos, the *Tokyo* subset (with font size scaled relative to this subset).
- When you click on a tag from this subset-tag cloud, say *2008*, I want all photos to be listed that are tagged with *Tokyo* **and** *2008* (instead of **all** photos tagged with *2008*), preferably *ad infinitum*.

I am new to Ruby, and just can't seem to accomplish either of these, no matter what I've tried (too much to list here).

Here is the relevant code:

photo.rb:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :photo
has_many :taggings, dependent: :destroy
has_many :tags, through: :taggings
accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags

def self.tagged_with(name)
    Tag.find_by_name!(name).photos
end

def self.tag_counts
    Tag.select("tags.*, count(taggings.tag_id) as count").
    joins(:taggings).group("taggings.tag_id")
end
```

tag.rb:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :taggings
    has_many :photos, through: :taggings
end
```

tagging.rb:

```
class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :tag
    belongs_to :photo
end
```

application_helper.rb:

```
module ApplicationHelper
def tag_cloud(tags, classes)
    max = 0
    tags.each do |t|
        if t.count.to_i > max
            max = t.count.to_i
        end
    end
    tags.each do |tag|
        index = tag.count.to_f / max * (classes.size - 1)
        yield(tag, classes[index.round])
    end
end
end
```

photos_controller.rb:

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController

  def index
      if params[:tag]
      @photos = Photo.tagged_with(params[:tag])
      else
      @photos = Photo.order("created_at desc").limit(8)
      end
  end

  private
  def set_photo
      @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
  end

  def photo_params
      params.require(:photo).permit(:name, :description, :picture, :tag_list, tags_attributes: :name)
  end
  end
```

index.html.erb:

```
<div id="tag_cloud">
  <% tag_cloud Photo.tag_counts, %w[xxs xs s m l xl xxl] do |tag, css_class| %>
  <%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag.name), class: css_class %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

photos.css.scss:

```
#tag_cloud {
  width: 400px;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  .xxs { font-size: 0.8em; COLOR: #c3c4c4; }
  .xs { font-size: 1.0em; COLOR: #b9bdbd; }
  .s { font-size: 1.2em; COLOR: #b0b5b5; }
  .m { font-size: 1.4em; COLOR: #9da6a6; }
  .l { font-size: 1.6em; COLOR: #8a9797; }
  .xl { font-size: 1.8em; COLOR: #809090; }
  .xxl { font-size: 2.0em; COLOR: #778888; }
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have possibility of selecting photos tagged with one of more tags. You need to change your function:

```
def self.tagged_with(*names)
    joins(:tags).where(tags: { name: names })
end
```

And name of param:

```
def index
  if params[:tags]
    @photos = Photo.tagged_with(params[:tags])
  else
    @photos = Photo.order("created_at desc").limit(8)
  end
end
```

And in view, when you define method `current_tags`:

```
<div id="tag_cloud">
  <% tag_cloud Photo.tag_counts, %w[xxs xs s m l xl xxl] do |tag, css_class| %>
  <%= link_to tag.name, tag_path([tag.name, *current_tags].uniq), class: css_class %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```